# Remove words from label inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, repeater

I'm trying to remove words from a label until it's under the specified allowed width. How ever while I'm looping over the repeaters items, the Width = 0 and the Text property is allways empty.

I've tried moving my code to OnItemDataBound

```
private void loadData()
{
    Activities activities = new Activities();
    var acts = activities.getNextActivities(3);
    if (acts.Count > 0)
    {
        rptActivities.DataSource = acts;
        rptActivities.DataBind();

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptActivities.Items)
        {
            Label lblActName = (Label)item.FindControl("lblActName");
            Unit width = lblActName.Width;
            while (width.Value > 310)
            {
                int pos = lblActName.Text.LastIndexOf(" ") < 0 ? 0 : lblActName.Text.LastIndexOf(" ");
                lblActName.Text = lblActName.Text.Substring(0, pos);
                width = lblActName.Width;
            }
        }
     }
     else
     {
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
        pnlNoItems.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `Width` property of the control doesn't dynamically calculate the width based on the content of the control; If you set the `Width` property, it will send it down in the HTML if there is a corresponding property on the HTML element that is generated.  See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.width(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: Your best bet is to come up with a number of characters (so `string.Length`) that you can fit comfortably and cut the data using that.

Comment: @ChrisShaffer The length property is 0 aswell while my foreach loop is running and as mentioned in the topic the text is empty. How can I run this code after the label is databound?

Comment: There are several ways you could do it; You could do it in the `activities.GetNextActivities()` method, or you could do it in the method above prior to binding the data to the Repeater.  If you are going to do it after binding, it should be done in an `OnItemDataBound` event handler.

Comment: Why not just _call_ the substring function?

Comment: @deostroll I am using the Substring method, but I want to remove whole words thats why I'm using the while loop

Comment: Could you show an example of how your input (string coming from db I assume) appears in the label control. Earlier I was just assuming something on the lines of this code: `str.Substring(0, maxWordLength > str.Length ? str.Length : maxWordLength)` where `maxWordLength` was the desired number of characters you require...